# Creating thin jar for submitting spark applications

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hadoop, jar, spark-submit

Any insights on how can we use thin jar to submit spark applications?

The scenario is such that if some specific dependency is not present in the classpath of the project or is specific to some distribution cloudera or hortonworks it throws an exception if the appropriate version of jars are not used.

How can we avoid such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The only thin jar you can make is one that doesn't compile the Spark core libraries into the JAR. For example Spark SQL and Spark Streaming don't need included, but unless Spark was compiled with Hive support during installation, you'll still need that one.

You'll need to contact your Hadoop cluster administrators to know what version of Spark is available, how it was built, and what libraries are available in `$SPARK_HOME` out of the box.

In my experience, I've never ran into a specific dependency to HDP or CDH as I've ran a Spark 2.3 job submitted to YARN fine, while neither vendor officially supports that version. The only thing you need is to match the Spark version with your code, not necessarily Hadoop/YARN/Hive versions. Kafka, Cassandra, other connectors are all extra anyway and they can't be in a thin jar

Comment: Thank you for your inputs,have a question,what do we need to do if we have some external dependency say for instance if we are using drools along with spark, how we can make sure that the spark job runs fine with thin jar as the drools jar would not be provided by any of the distribution(CDH or HDP).

Comment: Then you would include that as a fat jar, or add it to all executor classpaths and submit a thin jar